# How to call an xslt template which has no name?

Tags: xslt

My xslt template looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:param name="precedingPStyle" select="preceding-sibling::aic:pstyle[position()=1]/@name"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Is above a valid xslt template? How/when can this template be called? it has no name, only a match and the match has a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be called by `xsl:apply-templates` when it is the most appropriate template for the node selected. In the absence of any other more specific templates such as `match="text()[normalize-space(.)]"` this template would be applied for all text nodes.

For parameters, `apply-templates` supports `with-param` in exactly the same way as `call-template` does.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*/text()">
  <xsl:with-param name="precedingPStyle" select="'normal'"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The `with-param` select expression is evaluated in the context of the call, not the target node to which the template applies. As with `call-template`, any parameters that are not set with an explicit `with-param` will take the default value specified by the `select` expression on the `xsl:param` element in the template (which is evaluated in the context of the target, not the call)

Comment: what about the param? what if the value of the param will be null. Will the template be still called?